# Passing parameters to a class variable

Tags: document-classes, environment-variables

I'm trying to create my own colour theme for my document class. At the moment my solution is to use a class parameter:

```
\DeclareOption{colour-theme-formal}{
  \definecolor{soft}{gray}{0.75}
  \definecolor{glow}{RGB}{001,176,236}
  \definecolor{canvas}{RGB}{200,100,100}
  \definecolor{prime}{RGB}{255,100,100}
}
\DeclareOption{colour-theme-vibrant}{
  \definecolor{soft}{gray}{0.75}
  \definecolor{glow}{RGB}{001,176,236}
  \definecolor{canvas}{RGB}{255,100,100}
  \definecolor{prime}{RGB}{255,100,100}
}
```

So in setting up my document I do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,margin,line,colour-theme-vibrant]{jackstyle}
```

This works fine, but what I need is to have something I can change on the fly, rather than as a document parameter.

For example, it would be good to use a command to change between styles at any point I like, e.g:

```
\usetheme{colour-theme-vibrant}
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the class, before declaring the options, add

```
\newcommand{\jackclass@definetheme}[2]{\@namedef{jack@theme@#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\usetheme}[1]{\@nameuse{jack@theme@#1}}

\jackclass@definetheme{colour-theme-formal}{%
  \definecolor{soft}{gray}{0.75}%
  \definecolor{glow}{RGB}{001,176,236}%
  \definecolor{canvas}{RGB}{200,100,100}%
  \definecolor{prime}{RGB}{255,100,100}%
}
\jackclass@definetheme{colour-theme-vibrant}{%
  \definecolor{soft}{gray}{0.75}%
  \definecolor{glow}{RGB}{001,176,236}%
  \definecolor{canvas}{RGB}{255,100,100}%
  \definecolor{prime}{RGB}{255,100,100}%
}

\DeclareOption{colour-theme-formal}{\usetheme{colour-theme-formal}}
\DeclareOption{colour-theme-vibrant}{\usetheme{colour-theme-vibrant}}
```

You can then use `\usetheme{...}` wherever you prefer or use the class option (or both).

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks @egreg. I you have a moment, will you please explain the first 2 lines. My next step is to see if I can go one step further and use \newcommand inside a theme, but that does not work. For example, for one theme I would like single underline, for another I would like double.

Comment: @Jack I can't answer what you don't ask: single underline *where* and *how*? The first line defines `\jackclass@definetheme` so that `\jackclass@definetheme{a}{b}` does `\@namedef{jack@theme@a}{b}`, which becomes `\def\jack@theme@a{b}`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @egreg, I've asked a new question about this here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442692/creating-a-conditional-style-theme